# Publish game in Apple App store for Normal and Retina displays

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, app-store, retina-display

I developed a game using Cocos2d API for iPhone/iPod touch. My game supports normal graphics (480*320) and retina graphics (960*640).

Currently I have all my graphical resources packed in single projects, for example "LoadingScren.png" and "LoadingScreen@2x.png". I guess final release would have around 50MB (the game is not very big and not very complex).

Is this common scenario to have app prepared for normal graphics and retina?
I mean, "LoadingScreen.png" will never be used in Retina device and "LoadingScreen@2x.png" also will never be used by "normal" device! It's a waste of space.

Should I make two versions of the game?
But then, someone who has iPhone 3GS with non-hd version of the game, if lately they buy new iPhone 4/4S with retina support and restore data from backup to new device, they will remain with non-hd version on retina display (which is bad).

Any opinion and additional information regarding this matter is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK with two versions your user base is split in two, which can negatively affect your app's rankings.

Comment: btw, the recommended way in cocos2d is to use -hd images and not using the @2x style Apple uses, there are some incompatibilities (although the docs don't explain what they are).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I had always received a warning in CCFileUtils about not finding some graphics resources with "-hd" suffix, but as everything seemed ok on the device I just ignored that warning. I will change @2x to -hd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Only make one version of your app!**  Making a normal and @2x version of each graphic is how it is meant to be done.

When have you ever seen two versions of an app on the App Store, for "normal" or "retina" devices?  The entire reason Apple implemented the automatic @2x system is so that you could package it in one app.

As for the "waste of space", don't worry about it.  If your app is 50 MB, it means that even on the smallest-space iPhone (8gb) it uses about one-half of one-percent of storage - and nowadays Apple doesn't make any iPhones under 16gb.  A quarter of a percent is hardly a high price to pay.  Plus, most users could download a 50 mb game over WiFi in under a minute.

*(Often times "HD" versions on the App Store are references to iPad versions of an iPhone app)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's **normal to have just one version**. *Very* normal. I've never seen an app with both retina and non-retina versions.

You could instead just use the high-res graphics and leave the scaling to the OS; this would reduce the footprint of the graphics by approximately 25%, at the cost of some clarity and slowing down non-retina devices (which would be pretty slow anyway). However, the time and cost of implementing all this has to be balanced against the benefit -- which is improved performance on very old devices. Until your app is as popular as Angry Birds, this extra effort probably buys you far less than it costs.

Different graphics are often provided for iPad (HD) versions of apps, but that's usually because the apps are designed for a different aspect ratio and screen resolution. Such apps already suffer from diverse ratings sets, which is one benefit of universal apps.

Comment: Your non-retina graphics shouldn't be simply "scaled by 50%" versions of your retina graphics.  See http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, only make one version. When a retina display device loads up an image, it automatically searches for a copy of that images with the "-hd" tag at the end. If it cannot find one, then it uses the normal picture.

You shouldn't be using "@2x" at the end of your image, as it can cause some errors when using cocos2d. Instead, use "-hd", which is designed for cocos2d.

Examples:
image_1@2x DON'T USE THIS
image_1-hd USE THIS

Answer (score 0):

develop only one project using -HD images At The Staring Time Check Device And if it' iPhone Mean's(320,480) Then set image

```
    image_Scale  = scale/2;
```

Try This And Search on it.